# How to use Oracle SQL Developer connecting to the Oracle 12c running in the docker?

Tags: oracle, docker

I'm trying to use oracle sql developer connect the oracle 12c which is running in the docker(MAC OS), but getting an error：

An error was encountered performing the requested operation:

> IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
>   Vendor code 17002

I've installed oracle instant client and there is my `tnsnames.ora`

> ```
> orcl =
> (DESCRIPTION =
>     (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
>     (CONNECT_DATA =
>       (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
>     )
> )
> ```

[image]
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Have you selected SID or service name in the connection ? I use service name `ORCLPDB1` and It works for me  : I too use docker in Macos with Oracle for Linux image downloaded from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/index.html. I'm not sure how you created Oracle Database  image in docker. I had used this link to setup : https://dzone.com/articles/creating-an-oracle-database-docker-image and it works for me.

Comment: Hello,  Kaushik Nayak. I tried the ORCLPDB1 and got the same error. I installed the oracle followed this guide: https://oraclespin.com/2018/03/30/docker-installation-of-oracle-database-12c-on-mac/